# Swift returns optional("value") after upgrading to swift 2.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am new to swift and just followed a tutorial of sqlite, it runs great but after upgrading to swift 2.1 it appends "optional" to my result, how can I get rid of that?

**find data function**

```
    @IBAction func findContact(sender: UIButton)
    {
        if database.open() {
        let querySQL = "SELECT address, phone FROM CONTACTS WHERE name = '\(name.text)'"

            let results:FMResultSet? = database.executeQuery(querySQL,withArgumentsInArray: nil)
            if results!.next() == true {
                if let address1=results!.stringForColumn("address")
                {
                address.text = address1
                }

                phone.text = results!.stringForColumn("phone")
                status.text = "Record Found"
            } else {
                status.text = "Record not found"
                address.text = ""
                phone.text = ""
            }
            database.close()
        } else {
            print("Error: \(database.lastErrorMessage())", terminator: "")
        }
        }
```

**save data function**

```
@IBAction func saveData(sender: UIButton)
        {
            let database = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

            if database.open() {

                let insertSQL = "INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name, address, phone) VALUES ('\(name.text)', '\(address.text)', '\(phone.text)')"

                let result = database.executeUpdate(insertSQL,
                    withArgumentsInArray: nil)

                if !result {
                    status.text = "Failed to add contact"
                    print("Error: \(database.lastErrorMessage())", terminator: "")
                } else {
                    status.text = "Contact Added"
                    name.text = ""
                    address.text = ""
                    phone.text = ""
                }
            } else {
                print("Error: \(database.lastErrorMessage())", terminator: "")
            }

        }
```

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sde0p.png)

Comment: Try typing a name like "O'Hara" in your text field (a name that contains a single quote), type the Save button, and see your application fail. NEVER NEVER NEVER put raw values in your SQL. Instead, do `database.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name, address, phone) VALUES (?,?,?)" withArgumentsInArray: [name.text, address.text, phone.text])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not when you select the data.The problem is when you insert data.At the time of insert you just insert the optional values in your table like address field and phone number as shown in screenshot...So, at the time of insert you need to unwrap that optional values to avoid `optional()` keyword.

Comment: just updated my question with the saveData function, I am not inserting any optionals here

Comment: before insert...just print(name.text) ...and tell me output

Comment: Optional("myname")', 'Optional("the address")', 'Optional("+012345678")

Comment: solved by adding (name.text!) in the insert, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

`let querySQL = "SELECT address, phone FROM CONTACTS WHERE name = '\(name.text)'"`

you need to add exclamation mark end of the name.text ..

```
ecs: (name.text!)
```

May be it will help you.

Comment: it is not about the input as the query returns the correct data with "optional" keyword attached, anyways I tried your suggestion but this time it did not return anything at all